# Passing a variable length to declare new varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to declare a new variable with a length defined by a variable, something like this:

```
DECLARE @trimStringLength INT;
SET @trimStringLength = 48;

DECLARE @trimString VARCHAR(@trimStringLength);

SET @trimStringLength = '';
```

But I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near @trimStringLength. Expecting ID, integer or QUOTED_ID

Comment: What's the perceived advantage here over simply declaring a `varchar(max)`? It's not like you have to pay for the additional space that remains unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to dynamically specify variable type in MS SQL Server. The best thing that can be done is dynamically create / alter [User-Defined Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) and use this in the code.

If you just need to truncate the string by few characters, the correct approach would be to manipulate varchar(4000) / varchar(max) variables with string functions:

```
DECLARE @oldValue varchar(4000) = '123456789';
DECLARE @newValue varchar(4000) = LEFT(@oldValue, LEN(@oldValue)-1);
SELECT @newValue;
-- Result: 12345678
```

Comment: mean i can't declare a new field by a veriable's length

Comment: if i use 

        DECLARE @trimString Varchar(48);
        SET @trimStringLength='';

then work perfect

Comment: You can put the entire block of code into string, alter parameters (including length) and run it as dynamic SQL, but usually this is not a good idea.

Comment: Usually it's best to declare varchar(4000) / varchar(max) and just ignore the excess.

Comment: i want one less from above field

Comment: SELECT LEN(@have); 
here i get length of Have variable 
now i want to make a new field and copy the @have value to it

Comment: actually i'm trying to trim the sting by neglecting the last char of @have

Comment: @BasitRaza - then use the right tool for the job - `SUBSTRING`. Rather than relying on the side-effect of assigning to a too-small variable causing truncation.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server for `varchar(n)`

> Storage size is the actual length in bytes of the data entered, not n
>   bytes.

So, if you are not sure of the size, just declare `varchar(max)`

To remove last character

```
SET @trimString = SUBSTRING(@have, 0, LEN(@have)-1)
```

Comment: `DECLARE @trimString VARCHAR(max)`; then set it's value, size of data cell will readjust according to the size of your `@have` variable value

Comment: i want to copy "have" variable's value which is a long string
i want to copy it into "trimString" but neglect the last char of @have
is there any option.

Comment: `SET @trimString = SUBSTRING(@have, 0, LEN(@have))`